# Is it true that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} [f(x) g(y)] = [\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)][\lim\limits_{y\to b} g(y)]$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = A$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to b} g(y) = B$ with $A, B < \infty$. Then can we conclude that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} [f(x) g(y)]$ exists, and is equal to $AB$?

I tried: Given $\epsilon>0$, we want to find $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that if $\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|<\delta$, then $|f(x)g(y)-AB| < \epsilon$.

From the limits for $f$ and $g$, there is $\delta_f > 0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta_f$, then $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$.

Similarly, there is $\delta_g > 0$ such that if $|y-b|<\delta_g$, then $|g(y)-B|<\epsilon$.

In total, we have:
\begin{align*}
|f(x)g(y)-AB| &= |(f(x)-A)(g(y)-B) + f(x)B - AB + g(y)A - AB| \\
&\le |f(x)-A||g(y)-B| + |f(x)-A||B| + |g(y)-B||A| \\
&< \epsilon^2 + |B|\epsilon + |A|\epsilon,
\end{align*}
provided $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$.

**However, how can I choose $\delta$, and can we make it so that $|f(x)g(y)-AB| < \epsilon$ (not an expression of $\epsilon$)?**

The background behind is that I want to find $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^y \sin x}{x}$.  I used the inequality:
$$
e^y \cos x \le \frac{e^y \sin x}{x} \le e^y
$$
with the Squeeze Theorem, but I wonder if I can just split the limit.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the usual single variable rule that limit of product is product of limits? Mimic that proof.

Comment: One thing you might try is: for a given $\epsilon$, choose $\epsilon_1$ such that $\epsilon_1^2 + |B|\epsilon_1 + |A|\epsilon_1 < \epsilon$, then there exists $\delta = \delta(\epsilon_1)$ such that... and you can repeat your proof so far, inserting $\epsilon$ at the very end where you need it.